# Jquery Toggle Button image and Div Show/Hide

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, nav

I'm trying to create a toggle button image that also show's and hides a div.

This is working:
//html

```
    <body>
    <header>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('a#button').click(function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass("down");
                    $("nav").show("slow");
                });
            });
            </script>
        <a id="button" title="button"></a>
        <nav style="display: none">
            <ul>
                <li>NAV</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
</body>
```

//css

```
    a {
    background-image: url(../images/menu_on.gif);
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;     
    }

a.down {
    background-image: url(../images/menu_off.gif);
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block; 
    }
```

How do I get it to hide the "nav" again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$("nav").toggle("slow");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    $("nav").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  background-image: url(../images/menu_on.gif);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
a.down {
  background-image: url(../images/menu_off.gif);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="button" title="button">a</a>
<nav style="display: none">
  <ul>
    <li>NAV</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @luuuffy if this answers your question, please accept it.